# Kindly explain about the below formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can anyone tell me what `c1:c` is in the following formula, at the begining of the `INDIRECT` function:

```
IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,YEAR('Tab-3'!$D$3:$I$3)/(MMULT(COLUMN(INDIRECT("c1:c"&ROWS('Tab-3'!$C$4:$C$10),))^0,($B3='Tab-3'!$C$4:$C$10)*('Tab-3'!$D$4:$I$10>0))),COLUMNS($F3:F3)),"")
```

Comment: `c1:c` along with whatever number will follow is a range. That said, `COLUMN(INDIRECT("c1:c"&ROWS('Tab-3'!$C$4:$C$10),))^0` will always equal `1` since any whole number raised to the zeroeth power = 1 (except for `0`, but there is no Column 0 so that can't apply here)

Answer (score 1):

`C1:C` It's just a Range from `C1` to an undefined `C`. This part `&ROWS('Tab-3'!$C$4:$C$10)` is what defines the sigle C. `=ROWS()` Return the number of rows in a Range. So using `&` you can concatenate `C1:C` and what is return by `&ROWS('Tab-3'!$C$4:$C$10)` forms `C1:Cn`. Where `n` is most likely a number between 1 and 6(+1).

Cheers.

Comment: 'most likely between 1 and 6'? Under what circumstance would `=ROWS($C$4:$C$10)` return anything but `7`?

Comment: @AlexM damn I’m dumb